# Parse iOS relational query involving Parse User

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In my data model, I have a Session class with an 'owner' field that points to a 'User' instance. I'm trying to retrieve all the sessions owned by a given user for whom I only have his objectId. Here is my query:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Session"];
NSString *userId = ...;
[query whereKey:@"owner" equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"User" objectId:userId]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    //Here objects is always empty, even though I have several sessions whose 'owner' matches userId
}];
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, but I don't know what. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class with the name `User` is not the same as a `PFUser`. Internally I believe parse.com uses `_User` to refer to a PFUser object. Try changing the line:

`[query whereKey:@"owner" equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"User" objectId:userId]];`

to

`[query whereKey:@"owner" equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"_User" objectId:userId]];`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish that were documented somewhere.

Comment: It's actually visible in the Parse data browser, right beside the column name. Proper documentation would be awesome though.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and solved it as below

```
[query whereKey:@"studId" equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"_User" objectId:objUser.objectId]];
```

where **studId** is field of student class

Answer (score -1):

// Just add following code and that will be work and make sure you are passing objectID of user instead of just column name

[query include:@"owner"];